# A difficulty in understanding a solution of a differential equation in Vinberg section 0.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The differential equation is given in the following picture:

[image]

I believe that it is a separable differential equation, but because we differentiate with respect to you, I believe that the solution should be $$f(t) = C e^{ua}$$ instead of $$f(t) = C e^{ta},$$ could anyone clarify this for me please?

Comment: We differentiated the homomorphism identity with respect to $u$, but then set $u = 0$ so you end up with a differential equation in $t$, $f'(t) = f(t) a$, so the solution is a function of $t$.

Comment: but $f '(t) = df/du$ correct?@ChristopherA.Wong

Comment: No. See my answer.

Comment: @hopefully The function $f$ is a function of one variable. It does not matter what letter you call it. So $f'$ is the derivative of $f$ with respect to that variable. $f'(t)$ is that same derivative, evaluated at the point $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $ \frac{d}{du}f(t+u)=\frac{d}{du}f(t)f(u)$, hence $f'(t+u)=f(t)f'(u)$. With $u=0$ we get

$$f'(t)=f(t)f'(0).$$

Comment: what I am asking you are writing ..... in your writings$( ')$ is equivalent to differentiation with respect to u ... this is what you are writing

Comment: I think if you write the whole solution it may be clearer for me